# Unpacking a typelist

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

Lets say I have a function that takes just a type template parameter, I cannot change it's definition/implementation.

```
template < typename T >
void do_it();
```

Now I have a typelist defined a usual way, can't change it either:

```
template< typename ...Ts >
struct typelist;
```

I want to implement a **function** that takes a typelist, and runs do_it() on every type:

```
template< typename List >
void do_them();
```

The only solution I found up 'till now is:

```
template< typename T >
void do_them_impl()
{
   do_it<T>();
}

template< typename T, typename Ts...>
void do_them_impl()
{
   do_it<T>();
   do_them_impl<Ts...>();
}

template< template < typename...> class List, typename ...Ts >
void do_them_extract( List<Ts...>&& )
{
    do_them_impl< Ts >(); 
}

template< typename List >
void do_them()
{
    do_them_impl( List{} ); 
}
```

But that requires 4(!) functions for each case I want to create a single `do_them` function. I will require quite a few of those, and I don't want to write a quad of functions for each. Am I missing something?

C++14 welcome, C++17 solutions too, but marked as such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++14 you can use some awful tricks to introduce a valid pack expansion context:

```
template< template < typename...> class List, typename ...Ts >
void do_them_impl( List<Ts...>&& )
{
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
        (do_it<Ts>(), 0)...  
    };
}

template< typename List >
void do_them()
{
    do_them_impl( List{} ); 
}
```

This allows you to avoid recursive template instantiation, which is generally more expensive.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c0873f9b2473d9c)

---

In C++17 you can use [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template< template < typename...> class List, typename ...Ts >
void do_them_impl( List<Ts...>&& )
{       
    (do_it<Ts>(), ...);
}

template< typename List >
void do_them()
{
    do_them_impl( List{} ); 
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e26fef0a366ea917)

Comment: That was fast! C++14 - Is there a possibility to avoid std::initializer_list? (I'm coding without STL, various reasons). C++17 version - god, I cannot wait for this to be supported in Visual Studio -_-

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz yeah, you can use an array of integers or something like that: `int _[] = { 0, (do_it<Ts>(), 0)... };`. The first 0 is there to avoid 0 sized arrays, that are not valid in C++.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz I won't add another answer for that. It would worth to update this one and add the example with the array.

Comment: I'll leave this question open for 24h, and if nothing ingenious pops up, I'll accept this one -- saved me 2 functions (I can live with changing void do_them() to void do_them( typelist<Ts...>&& ) )

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz is something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WahiJACV78G8NGj2) what you are looking for?

Comment: Don't want to use a struct because in fact it's a method, struct in class with `this` passing looks really messy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that takes advantage of C++14's generic lambdas:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_ { using type = T; };

template <typename Type>
using type = typename Type::type;

template <typename List>
struct map_;

template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
struct map_<Container<Ts...>>
{
    template <typename Fun>
        void operator()(Fun&& fun)
        {
            (void)((int[sizeof...(Ts)]){(fun(type_<Ts>{}), 0)...});
        }
};

template <typename List>
auto map = map_<List>{};
```

Then for each function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
const char * type_name()
{
        return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}

template <typename T>
void do_it()
{
    std::cout << type_name<T>() << std::endl;
}
```

you can write:

```
template <typename List>
void do_them()
{
    map<List>([](auto v){ do_it<type<decltype(v)>>(); });
}

template <typename... Ts>
struct typelist {};

int main()
{
    do_them<typelist<int, char, bool>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with -O3 gives the same assembly as if we simply called `do_it<int>`, `do_it<char>`, `do_it<bool>` in succession.