# C++ variadic function template with multiple typelists

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, partial-specialization

[Compiler Explorer Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/G6aWez8qE) shows what I have found that works as well as a commented out section showing what I want, but that doesn't work.

I am new to C++ and I am trying to write a sqlite3 interface in C++20 that has type checking for query parameters and returned column types. I have been stuck for several days now and have read so much. I am sure that one of these has my answer, but I just don't understand this stuff well enough to figure out what my issue is:

- [Variadic template constructor with multiple parameters packs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663639/variadic-template-constructor-with-multiple-parameters-packs)
- [template template variadic parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712096/template-template-variadic-parameter-pack)
- [C++ variadic template return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831474/c-variadic-template-return-type)
- [How can I have multiple parameter packs in a variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831501/how-can-i-have-multiple-parameter-packs-in-a-variadic-template)
- [Unpacking a typelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002126/unpacking-a-typelist)

Ultimately, this is what I would like to work

```cpp
template <class... T>
struct Typelist {};

struct Database {
    Database(const string &sql) {}
    template <class Input, class Output>
    void Query(Input input) {}
    

    // error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization
    // 'Query<Typelist<Inputs ...>, Typelist<Outputs ...> >' is not allowed
    template <class... Inputs, class... Outputs>
    vector<tuple<Outputs...>> Query<Typelist<Inputs...>, Typelist<Outputs...>>(
        const string &sql, Inputs... inputs) {}
};

int main() {
    Database db(":memory:");
    vector<tuple<string, string>> people =
        db.Query<Typelist<int, float>, Typelist<string, string>>(
            "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE id = ? AND somefloat = ?;", 1, 42.0f);
}
```

Any observations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text. What's the exact problem you're having? Are you asking how to iterate over all types in both lists? Also consider using an existing wrapper, e.g. [sqlite++](https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Updated with a more complete example. The Compiler Explorer links also has some close working solution, but not the one I would like. The exact problem I am having is that my desired interface does not compile. I am able to use fold expressions to iterate over all types and use `index_sequence` to get the relative positions. This is a learning exercise so a wrapper would be counter-productive. Thanks.

Comment: I see. Since partially specializing functions is not allowed, you need a helper template class (that you're going to partially specialize) with a static function in it. Move all logic to that helper function, and call it from your existing function.

Comment: _"I am new to C++ and I am trying to write a sqlite3 interface in C++20"_ tagged "variadic templates" and "metaprogramming"...  well, that escalated quickly. Maybe start simple? 

Comment: I do not understand how this is supposed to work.Are you trying to do something like `std::format` but for sql queries? Basically, are you writing type-safe `sqlite_exec_printf`? I do not understand why do you need `Typelist<int, float>` you already have the types, `1` is an `int`, `42.0f` is a float, no need to specify them. Because this is a great theoretical example, but it may be you are asking XY question.

Comment: Overall, writing `std::format` is very hard. It would _very_ easier to use `sqlite3_str_appendf` and use `std::cout` formatting, and then write a recursive lambda to pass to `sqlite3_exec` to read the return values. This is _not_ someone new in C++ would take on.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, I see now that partial specialization isn't allowed for function templates. Thanks, I am able to work with the technique you described.

Comment: @JHBonarius haha, I suppose it's all relative.. I've devoted most of my free time the last 3 months to learning as much as I can and this is just where I found myself spinning my wheels.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you need template specialization?

What about simply using overloading?

If you switch the `Input...` / `Output...` in the template declaration

```
template <typename ... Outputs, typename ... Inputs>
```

you can explicit the `Output...` list in the call and the `Input...` list is deduced from the `inputs...` arguments

```
std::vector<std::tuple<Outputs...>> Query(const std::string &sql, Inputs... inputs) {}
```

You can call `Query()` as follows

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> people =
    db.Query<std::string, std::string>(
        "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE id = ? AND somefloat = ?;", 1, 42.0f);A
```

Observe also that your compiler explore example compile if you simply rename `Query2()` as `Query()`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct Database
{
  Database(std::string const & sql)
  {}

  template <typename Input, typename Output>
  void Query(Input input)
  {}

  template <typename ... Outputs, typename ... Inputs>
  std::vector<std::tuple<Outputs...>>
    Query(std::string const & sql, Inputs... inputs)
  {}
};

int main()
{
  Database db(":memory:");

  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>> people =
    db.Query<std::string, std::string>(
      "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE id = ? AND somefloat = ?;",
      1, 42.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `std::format` is extremely hard. Use the same approach as `std::cout` - one object that you can `<<` add to.

May this short example written in a very short time show you how to use `sqlite3_str_appendf` to construct the query string and how to convert output parameters, but most importantly encourage learning *a lot* more about C++ programming. This is merely a template written in a very short time to show the interface, untessted - a real interface would be expected to be much more well thought through.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

// C callabck for sqlite3_exec
extern "C"
int query_C_trampoline(void *cookie, int n, char **d, char **c) {
    auto f = reinterpret_cast<std::function<int(int, char **, char **)>*>(cookie);
    return (*f)(n, d, c);
}

// the output conversion functions
template<typename T>
void query_assign(char *data, char *column, T& to);
template<>
void query_assign(char *data, char *column, std::string& to) {
    to = data;
}
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename ...T>
void query_assign_recursive(char **data, char **column, std::tuple<T...>& res) {
    query_assign(*data, *column, std::get<I>(res));
    if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(T)) {
        query_assign_recursive<I + 1>(data++, column++, res);
    }
}

struct Query {
    sqlite3_str *s{};
    sqlite3 *db{};
    Query(sqlite3 *db) : db(db) {
        s = sqlite3_str_new(db);
        if (s == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("something");
    }
    ~Query() {
        // TODO free(s) at least
    }
    void _herr() {
        if (sqlite3_str_errcode(s)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("something");
        }
    }
    Query& operator<<(const char *t) {
        sqlite3_str_appendf(s, "%s", t);
        _herr();
        return *this;
    }
    Query& operator<<(int t) {
        sqlite3_str_appendf(s, "%d", t);
        _herr();
        return *this;
    }
    Query& operator<<(float t) {
        sqlite3_str_appendf(s, "%f", t);
        _herr();
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename ...T>
    std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> exec() {
        std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> ret{};
        std::function<int(int, char **, char**)> cb = [&](int count, char **data, char **column) {
            std::tuple<T...> col;
            if (count != sizeof...(T)) throw std::runtime_error("count");
            // recursively assing tuple elements, as above
            query_assign_recursive(data, column, col);
            ret.emplace_back(col);
            return 0;
        };
        char *errmsg{};
        // trampoline only calls std::function
        int e = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlite3_str_value(s), query_C_trampoline, &cb, &errmsg);
        if (e) std::runtime_error((const char *)errmsg);
        return ret;
    }
};

int main() {
    sqlite3 *ppdb;
    sqlite3_open("/tmp/a", &ppdb);
    auto res = 
         (Query(ppdb)
            << "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE id = "
            << 1
            << " AND somefloat = "
            << 42.0f
            << ";"
         ).exec<std::string, std::string>();
    for (auto&& i : res) {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << ' ' << std::get<1>(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this -it's clear you put quite a lot of work into this answer which I appreciate. My original post was purely a learning exercise I was interested in. I do have years of study ahead of me, and your answer will give me an opportunity to learn even more.